# Tell me when a tweeted question is from Meta, please

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, twitter

I found out recently that the automated twitter accounts for SE sites also tweet hot Meta posts. While I have no objection to this, I would greatly prefer if this were to be made clear to followers, which tweets are about questions on Main, and which on Meta.

[Sometimes](https://twitter.com/StackJudaism/status/546129318943141888) it will be clear that it's a Meta post, but [other times](https://twitter.com/StackJudaism/status/547083200821223425) it's decidedly [less clear](http://twitter.com/#!/StackJudaism/status/473899780137963520).

**Proposed change:** add the word "Meta" to the beginning of a tweeted Meta question, like so:

> **Meta:** [question title]  #top-tag-on-question

Comment: Good thing Twitter provides a generous character limit to allow for things like this.

Comment: @Shog9 `Meta: ` ...I count 6 characters :P